# Why does the for-loop only create one file?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to write a program for my Raspberry Pi, which will create audio files of morse code. I then manually send out these files with pifm. But thats not really important. This started as a school project, where i made a program to convert text to morse code. That works perfectly fine. Because i was already expirementing with pifm i thaught it would be cool to actually create sound files using python.
So my idea was to read the text file where i saved my morsecode, and find out its length. Then i wanted to do an for-loop till that length, where i then test if the string is a dot or dash, and then create the sine wave. That works perfectly fine for one character, but i dont seem to see my problem with the loop. I decided to create a new wav file for every dot/dash.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write


file = open("text.txt", "r")
l = file.read()
number_of_characters = len(l)

for x in range(0, number_of_characters):
    print(f"x: {x}, number_of_characters: {number_of_characters}")
    if l[x] == '.' :
        rate = 44100  # Sampling rate [samples/s].
        n = 44100 * 1     # Length [samples].
        f = 440     # Frequency of the sine [Hz].
        t = np.linspace(0, n / rate, n, endpoint=False)
        s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * t)
        write('sine_' + str(x) + '.wav', rate, np.round(s*32767).astype(np.int16))
        
    elif l[x] == '_':
        rate = 44100  # Sampling rate [samples/s].
        n = 44100 * 2   # Length [samples].
        f = 440     # Frequency of the sine [Hz].
        t = np.linspace(0, n / rate, n, endpoint=False)
        s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * 2*t)
        write('sine_' + str(x) + '.wav', rate, np.round(s*32767).astype(np.int16))
```

I first had a for-loop which looked like
`for x in number_of_characters`
but i thaught that i would better use range to run the loop properly, but it still does not seem to work. If anyone could help that would be very much appreciated.
If i made any stupid mistakes i apologize, we use lazarus(pascal) in school, and im not very familiar with python, but i wanted to try out something new :)

Thanks for all the help, i had some fairly stupid mistakes, but it all works well now :)
I've edited my final code above, the way it is it works fine for what i intend it to do!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: You're reassigning `s` inside the if/else branches, so the comparisons `s[x] == '.'` and `s[x] == '_'` are never true afterwards.

Comment: just as a general tip, the easiest way to debug this is probably something like adding a bunch of print statements. eg `print(f"x: {x}, number_of_characters: {number_of_characters}")` at the start of your loop, a print statment that says `print("s[x] == '.'! entering if statement...")` at the first line of the if statement, etc

Comment: Why are you reading from the file twice? Both `s` and `data` are the contents of the same file.

Comment: I chnaged the s[x] to l[x] now, i didnt even realise i used s for two different things. But the loop still only runs once :/

Comment: You are assigning `l` twice for no reason. Is it really you intention to write a separate file with a different file name for each character? You are not closing the files after writing. Other suggestions 1. there is much repeated code inside your loop - move it outside 2. Use clear, informative names not single letters it makes later understanding much easier.

Comment: hey,
maybe a stupid question, but why is it necessary to close the files after writing? Don't they close on their own? also, if i move the code for creating the sine wave outside, will it still properly make the sine waves? Thanks in advance for an answer!

Comment: You have only two sorts of `.wav` files - dot and dash. Yet you **recalculate** the content to be written out at every character. Why not just calculate each once outside the loop and also avoid repeated code then just write out **dot_data** or **dash_data** as required, I don't really understand why you want presumably a very large number of files with the exact same content but different names but presumably there is some purpose. It's good practice to close opened files but it does look like this is intrinsic in the `scipy.io.wavfile.write code`